# Private Ethereum network nodes cannot be created using a different port address

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, json-rpc

I'm trying to create a private Ethereum network, hence I need to run each node on a different port. However, it wouldn't accept the port number when I assigned a new port number. It uses the default port number.

**Starting bootnode:**

```
bootnode -nodekey “./boot.key” -verbosity 7 -addr “127.0.0.1:30301”
```

**Node1 creation code:**

```
geth --networkid 20213 --datadir "./data" --bootnodes enode://b31db920ae792d67396bc195a7aa5c1ba685cfcb9e3fd4a3c77e7c63542d3f2e3196f2878c35bb3951e409fefcb7183d22b946250012209f55e6bce5a19a2575@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30301 --port 30304 --ipcdisable --syncmode full --http --allow-insecure-unlock --http.corsdomain "*" --http.port 8546 --unlock 0x1358679CAFE2b9f0Defc1714B317097E8CB9F4B1 --password password.txt --mine console
```

You can see a few lines of my console once the above command has completed. The http server was launched on a different port, but when authentication failed, it switched to the default port.

[image]

**Node2 creation code:**

```
geth --networkid 20213 --datadir "./data" --bootnodes enode://b31db920ae792d67396bc195a7aa5c1ba685cfcb9e3fd4a3c77e7c63542d3f2e3196f2878c35bb3951e409fefcb7183d22b946250012209f55e6bce5a19a2575@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30301 --port 30306 --ipcdisable --syncmode full --http --allow-insecure-unlock --http.corsdomain "*" --http.port 8547 --unlock 0xC53637b4af259F6A93f279A576F3Fa63CCDEA69f --password password.txt console
```

**1.How can I use a different port for each node?**

**2.Do I need to make any changes to my local machines' settings in order to authorize new ports?**

Answer (score 0):

Your node2 folder need to change it to

```
geth --networkid 20213 --datadir "./data2" --bootnodes enode://b31db920ae792d67396bc195a7aa5c1ba685cfcb9e3fd4a3c77e7c63542d3f2e3196f2878c35bb3951e409fefcb7183d22b946250012209f55e6bce5a19a2575@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30301 --port 30307 --ipcdisable --syncmode full --http --allow-insecure-unlock --http.corsdomain "*" --http.port 8547 --authrpc.port 8552 --unlock PUT_A_NEW_ACCOUNT_INTO_NODE2 --password password.txt console
```